# Is there a way to sort an ENTIRE array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

As part of an experiment with genetic learning algorithms, it would be useful to be able to sort an entire array of 'genes' into fitness order. So far the only answers I can find in the community deal with the highest, or second highest values and so forth.

Has anyone developed a robust array sorting method that could be implemented in C++? It seems a lot of implementation involve the ( int i : array) method which is not universally accepted by all C++ platforms.

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Not sure what you got from result, but sorting in general re-arranges _all_ the elements in increasing/decreasing order

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/
...
And there are plenty more on the internet

Comment: `std::sort` perhaps ?

Comment: As @JonathanPotter says, for raw arrays you can use `std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));`.

Comment: Many thanks, that's a great help - I am new to C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use `std::sort` as defined in `<algorithm>`?  See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).  You can also define a custom comparator.

Sample usage is as follows

```
std::sort(someArray,someArray+lengthOfArray);
std::sort(someVector.begin(),someVector.end());
```

`stable_sort` also exists, if you need it.

The custom comparator can be useful if fitness is not a straight `<` operator (eg involving some simulation).  Then you can do something like this

```
struct {
    bool operator()(gene a, gene b)
    {   
        // However you compare genes for fitness.  Not specific code,
        // just an example.
        a.simulateLife();
        b.simulateLife();
        return a.fitness < b.fitness;
    }   
} geneCompare;
std::sort(genes.begin(),genes.end(),geneCompare);
```

In addition, perhaps you do not *need* to sort the whole array.  If for example, only 20 out of 100 genes survive the timestep, you only want the first 20 values.  In this case `std::partial_sort` is your friend.  More info [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort).

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I came across nothing like this in various algorithm textbooks so thanks!

Comment: The custom comparator is a bit suspect. Evaluating fitness that way may cause intransitive results. I.e. gene a < gene b, gene b < c but also gene c < gene a. `std::sort` cannot handle that.

Comment: Right.  But it is useful to see an example.  Will update the comparator.